# Unable to access Method from Subclass

Tags: java

**I'm just trying to use Method_In_SubClass() method from SubClass Class but I'm getting these errors. I tried by changing Method_In_SubClass to Static but still getting errors**

```
public class Sub {

//Method 1 : Non-Static
public void  nonstatictest(){
    System.out.println("This is non-Static method.");
}

//Mehod 2 : Static
public static void statictest(){
    System.out.println("This is static method.");
}

//SubClass 
public class SubClass{

    //Method in SubClass
    public void Method_In_SubClass(){
            System.out.println("This is Method in SubClass");
    }
}


public static void main(String args[]){
        Sub SubObject = new Sub();
        SubClass SubClassobject = new SubClass();
        SubObject.nonstatictest();
        statictest();
        SubClassobject.Method_In_SubClass();

}
}
```

**Error:**

```
Sub.java:25: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
            SubClass SubClassobject = new SubClass();
                                        ^
1 error
```

Then I changed Method_In_SubClass to static but getting this error

```
Error :Illegal static declaration in inner class Sub.SubClass
        public static void Method_In_SubClass(){
                           ^
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations
Sub.java:25: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
            SubClass SubClassobject = new SubClass();
```

Comment: It's the inner class itself you need to make static (`public static class SubClass`). Since you instantiate it, you don't need to make its method static

Comment: There are two options. Either you can make your inner class static or try to instantiate your `subClass` in the correct way. You can read about how to do it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: @Aaron and  prashantpiyush both are correct and the solutions worked for me  Thank you both of you.

Answer (score 0):

Both Main and SubClass are members of class Sub and you cannot reference a non-static member of class sub that is SubClass in Main which is a static member. You need make the entire SubClass into static instead of just the Method_In_SubClass().

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way to make it work is by making SubClass as Static

```
 public static class SubClass{

    //Method in SubClass
    public void Method_In_SubClass(){
            System.out.println("This is Method in SubClass");
    }
}
```

I assumed that initiating SubClass Object/Instance of the class would be same as Parent class but it's not

<strike>SubClass SubClassobject = new SubClass();</strike>

The correct way of initiating an object of the subclass is :

```
Sub.SubClass SubClassobject = SubObject.new SubClass();
```